# Does Hammock(C#) rest framework support "Batch Requests" feature provided by Facebook Graph API?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I want to use a framework(C#) for Facebook Graph API, and Hammock is one option.
Can someone please suggest me a good library which supports all features of Graph API including batch request feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/), which [supports batched requests.](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Batch-Requests.aspx)